# How to convert a set of pointer to a set of const pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constants, containers

I have a class `Data`:

```
class Data {
private:
    int d;
public:
    int Get() const {
        return d;
    }
    void Set(int d) {
        this->d = d;
    }
};
```

and a class `Manager` to manage a set of `Data`:

```
class Manager {
private:
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Data>> dataSet;
public:
    const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>* GetDataSet();
};
```

I want to get the `dataSet` from class `Manager` using `GetDataSet()`, but I don't want others to modify the set or the data. So I want the return type of `GetDataSet()` to be a const pointer to a set of const pointers. However, I can't directly `return &dataSet` in `GetDataSet()` because `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Data>>` can't be converted to `std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>`.

One way to solve the problem is to make a copy of the set. But it has extra costs. Another way is to make the `Set()` function of class `Data` private, and let the class `Manager` be a friend of class `Data`. But it will expose all the private fields of class `Data` to class `Manager`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. Part of the reason has to do with certain design deficiencies of std::shared_ptr.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the shared pointer to begin with?  If you just use std::set<Data> then you can provide public access to a const reference of the set.  On a side note, it is also strange to see the use of shared pointer while simultaneously providing a public method which returns a raw pointer.

Comment: @qexyn My `Data` class is actually big. I have two data sets in `Manager` class consist of almost the same set of data, while one set is sorted by property `a`, and the other by `b`. Sometimes I get the first few elements from one set and remove them from the other. So I chose to use pointer.

Comment: @qexyn If I make my dataSet a smart pointer `std::shared_ptr<std::set<std::shared_ptr<Data>>> dataSet;`, and return a smart pointer, it still can't be converted. `std::shared_ptr<const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>> GetDataSet() {return std::shared_ptr<const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>>(dataSet);}`

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice solution would be to construct and return a 
`std::vector<const Data*>`, since you don't want to share ownership (I assume) with the caller. Unless `GetDataSet()` is used very often, I think it shouldn't effect performance too much.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe C pointer casting may help, it easier when you use typedefs.

like this:

```
typedef std::set<std::shared_ptr<Data>> DataSet;
typedef const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>> ConstDataSet;
class Manager {
private:
    DataSet dataSet;
public:
    ConstDataSet* GetDataSet(){
        return  (ConstDataSet*) &dataSet;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**
I just tried it in visual studio 10 Express and it worked.

I guess it work just because `std::shared_ptr<Data>` and `std::shared_ptr<const Data>` have the same structure.

Comment: It works for me as well. I tried `return &((const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>)dataSet);` but didn't try `return (const std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Data>>*)&dataSet;`. I think it should work as expected too. But since someone minus this answer, I wonder does it have any deficiency?

Comment: I guess the down-voters angry because I didn't used `return reinterpret_cast<ConstDataSet*>(&dataSet);` which also works... :)